# Is this conditional expectation of a differential equation increasing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, functional-equations, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, and $f(y, a):R^2\rightarrow R$ be a linear function that is increasing in both arguments.

Also assume that at any $a$ the following holds

$X - f(Y,a) + E'[X|a] = 0$

Taking $E[\cdot|a]$ on both sides of above equality yields

$E[X|a] - E[f(Y,a)|a] + E'[X|a] = 0$

**Main Question:** Under what additional restrictions on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ and the functional form of $f$ is

$E[X|a] := E[X|X - f(Y,a) + E'[X|a] = 0]$

increasing in $a$?

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then I believe $E[X|a]$ should be increasing. However, I have trouble proving this, or even figuring out what concepts or terms to look for. So any help is appreciated!

**Side Question**: What terms or concepts would I look for, if I wanted to tackle this problem?

**Context**: $(X, Y)$ represent types of decision makers. I know that given their type $(X, Y)$ a decision maker will choose $a$ such that
$X - f(Y,a) + E'[X|a] = 0$, where the decision maker takes $E'[X|a]$ as given. The expectations are taken over different types.

Comment: What are $E[\cdot\mid a]$ and $E'[\cdot]$?

Comment: @Sayantan For a given level of $a$, the equation holds for any realization of (X, Y). Hence, I can take expectations of both sides of the equation over X, Y, yielding $E[\cdot|a]$. $E'$ is the derivative of that function with respect to $a$.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear to me. Do you mean $E[X|a]=E[X|(X,Y)=a]$ or something like this?

Comment: robust, @Sayantan, perhaps $E[X|a] = E[X|X=a]$ ?

Comment: Dumb question: $E[X|a] \color{red}{:}= E[X|X - f(Y,a) + E'[X|a] = 0]$? --> Is this a definition? Otherwise, I don't understand the question. How can an equation be increasing in $a$? Oh, perhaps you're asking how $E[X|a]$ is increasing in $a$ and you're pointing out $E[X|a] = E[X|X - f(Y,a) + E'[X|a] = 0]$ ?

Comment: robust, @Sayantan, re $E'[X|a]$, my guesses are 1. Malliavin calculus 2. [Derivatives of conditional expectations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83305) 3. $\exists$ Borel function $g$ s.t. $E[X|a] = g(a)$ by [Conditional expectation as Borel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670741) ?

Comment: Sayantan @BCLC Sorry, I am clearly unclear with my notation. I mean that I require that $E[X|a] = E[X|X - f(Y, a) + E'[X|a] = 0]$ holds.

Comment: @robust ugh ok but you still didn't answer the other questions...

Comment: @BCLC The equality of $E[X|a]=E[X|X−f(Y,a)+E′[X|a]=0$ follows from the fact that at a given $a$, we know $X−f(Y,a)+E′[X|a]=0$; I'm unsure whether that makes it a definition. I am not asking *how* $E[X|a]$ is increasing in a, but *whether*. Hopefully those are the other questions you meant. I also added some context to the question.

Comment: robust, what is $E[X|a]$ ? Is $a$ an event? a random variable? a $\sigma$-algebra? a number in which case $E[X|a] := E[X|X=a]$ ?

Comment: @BCLC From the context a is a number, and $E[X|a] \not = E[X|X=a]$. However, in the context agents draw $(X, Y)$ and then choose $a$. So in this sense, $a$ is an event: Only a subset of realizations of $(X, Y)$ can choose $a$ (namely those who satisfy the $\dotsc =0$ equation). If this helps you, could you help me re-formulate the question in a clearer way?

Comment: @robust 1. Where did you get this? 2. I don't get really get it. a is a number yet also an event. I guess this can happen if a represents the singleton containing a. So the sample space is R? N? Be as explicit as possible. Assume I know only the basics of advanced probability. How does one compute derivatives with respect to numbers in singletons? Please provide a reference or give an example for such derivatives. Another thing that comes to mind is using dirac measure instead of indicator functions. Is that relevant?

Comment: @BCLC Thank you for following up. 1. [Background of the setup](https://www.princeton.edu/~rbenabou/papers/AER%202006.pdf) 2. $a \in R$, it is not a singleton. Imagine $(X, Y)$ determine what kind of person you are, but only you know that. Depending on your realization you choose a level of $a$. An outsider observes $a$ and tries to infer (the expected value of) what person you are. The derivative then says how the outsider changes his inference about you, if he observes a marginally bigger $a$. I unfortunately don't see the dirac measure connection. Does the context make things a bit clearer?