# Conditional expectation at a single point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Given two random variables, the conditional expectation $E(Y|X)$ is a $\sigma(X)$ measurable random variable whose integration over any set in $\sigma(X)$ agrees with the integration of $Y$ over the same set.

What does the notation $E(Y | X = x)$ mean? One immediate guess is that it means $E(Y | X) |_{X = x}$. Then for this to be well-defined $E(Y|X)$ must be constant over $\{X = x\}$. Does this definition even make sense cause if $X$ is a continuous random variable then $\{X = x\}$ should be a set of measure zero, then the integral of $E(Y|X)$ over this set is automatically zero, how do we infer the value of $E(Y|X)$ over this set then?

Comment: [This pdf](https://pizzaseminar.speicherleck.de/skript4/0x-conditional-expectation/ConditionalExpectation.pdf) I think is fantastic for clarifying conditional expectation, which can otherwise be pretty confusing!

Comment: @jlammy that pdf contains only one reference, so one might say: *render unto Caesar the things that are Caesar's*

Answer (score 1):

Consider $E[Y|X]$ where $E[|Y|]<\infty$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670741/conditional-expectation-as-borel-function/2198098) $E[Y|X]=h(X)$ for some Borel $h$. We *define* $E[Y|X=x]:=h(x)$. For a reference see [Klenke's Probability Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-5361-0), Corollary 1.97 p. 38 and Definition 8.24 p. 180.